# textbox validation accepting IPs in javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox, ip

I want to have a validation function it must accept 3 types:

```
var
portvar
ipvar
```

one of my problems is in IPvar
user input must be in this syntax as example:

```
[192.168.1.0/24,10.1.1.0/24]
```

how can I accept just such Ips from textboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check it against a regular expression like this:

```
var textVal = ...;
if ((/^\[(?!,)(,?(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\/[1-9]\d*)+\]$/).test(textVal)) {
  alert('Valid!');
}
else {
  alert('Invalid!');
}
```

The regular expression identifies valid IP's with each part of the IP being a number between 0 and 255. Additionally, as your example shows, each IP must be followed by a single `/` and then a number representing the subnet mask. Lastly, multiple IPs are separated by commas (however the regular expression does not allow a comma at the very beginning or the very end).

(By the way, the second IP address in your example isn't valid).

Comment: after / isn't it a subnet mask?

Comment: if I don't put comma again it will tell valid

Comment: would you please tell me what are these?(/^\[(?!,)

Comment: `/^\[(?!,)` means the line must begin with a bracket and should not be immediately followed by a comma.

Comment: I got it thanks jerluc, can you tell me 25[0-5] means 250 till 255? what is {3}? and the sign =>:

Comment: Yep that's exactly what the `25[0-5]` means. And `{3}` refers to the previous pattern repeating exactly 3 times. And if you're referring to `(?:` that denotes a non-capturing group, meaning the matched value won't be captured for later use.